# Why free() impact other variable's value?

Tags: c, free

Practice for "Distinct Subsequences" online:

> Given a string S and a string T, count the number of distinct subsequences of T in S.
>
> A subsequence of a string is a new string which is formed from the original string by deleting some (can be none) of the characters without disturbing the relative positions of the remaining characters. (ie, "ACE" is a subsequence of "ABCDE" while "AEC" is not).
>
> Here is an example:
>   S = "rabbbit", T = "rabbit"
>
> Return 3.

My code is listed below.

For test case `{s="aaaaaaaaaaaaa", t="aa"}`:

If I enable `//free(pMtx);` before final return, my codes will treated as failure with a result `79`.

If I keep this `free(pMtx);` commented out, my result is correct `78`.

Then I tried on my local PC, everything is fine with `free(pMtx);` enabled.

Therefore I'm really confused why this happens?

```
int numDistinct(char* s, char* t) {
    int slen=strlen(s);
    int tlen=strlen(t);
    if( (0 == slen) || (0 == tlen)||(tlen>slen))
        return 0;

    int* pMtx = (int*)malloc(slen*tlen*sizeof(int));

    for(int ss=0; ss<slen; ss++)
    {
        if(0==ss)
        {
            pMtx[0] = (s[0]==t[0]) ? 1 : 0;
            continue;
        }

        for(int tt=0; tt<tlen; tt++)
        {
            int cur = ss*tlen + tt;

            if(tt>ss)
            {
                pMtx[cur]=0;
                continue;
            }

            int v1 = (tt==0) ? 1 : pMtx[cur-tlen-1];
            int vv = v1 + pMtx[cur-tlen];

            if(s[ss]==t[tt])
                pMtx[cur] = (vv>=pMtx[cur-tlen]) ? vv : pMtx[cur-tlen];
            else
                pMtx[cur] = pMtx[cur-tlen];
        }
    }

    int rst = pMtx[slen*tlen-1];

    //free(pMtx);  //------------> open it will result in wrong rst value ???

    return rst;    
}
```

Comment: You said it works on your PC but not on another machine. What kind of system has the problem? Also, please provide a complete program which we can run through a compiler.

Comment: it's on oj.leetcode.com, question 115. I just wrote a main function to call this function with two char arrays.

Comment: I tried your code with a simple main and a main that call function. All is working well. What is your platform? Which compiler? @Dayalrai return VALUES ot local variable is usual and correct. Return pointer of local variable is not correct...

Comment: `valgrind` complains of using "uninitialized values". This is because you *allocate* memory and then possibly *use* it in the `Mtx[cur] = (vv>=pMtx[cur-tlen]) ? ..` line without ever having written to it. On some systems and/or in "debug" mode, allocated memory may be cleared automatically but you'd better not rely on that.

Comment: I understand local variables will be dissolved when function returns. But I don't think return value could be random value because of this. Moreover, each time the wrong return value is always 79 if free() is called, that's really weird.

Comment: the link of this online question: https://leetcode.com/problems/distinct-subsequences/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    if(0==ss)
    {
        pMtx[0] = (s[0]==t[0]) ? 1 : 0;
        continue;
    }
```

You need to initialize `pMtx[0]` to `pMtx[tlen-1]`, not just the first element.

The first time you allocate memory, it is often zeroed out (because the OS may have done it before giving it to the process). When you free memory, it can get reused the next time you allocate memory and then it won't be zero anymore. So if you call this function more than once from main it explains why it fails.

Comment: Not clear: How can this solution change result of function with or without a free???

Comment: malloc doesn't zeros heap... BTW I think that OP is seeing something that doesn't belong to the posted code. I tried his code and it return 78 always with or without the free.

Comment: Malloc doesn't zero heap but the OS may zero out the heap during program loading. Unless the OP specifies the environment he is using we can all just keep guessing

Comment: Try calling the function multiple times from main, then you will get erroneous results...

Comment: @LPs: not true *in general* – some compilers do this in debug mode. Anyway, if you initialize the array to anything else but `0`, you *will* get another result, showing that the initial values *are* important.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I initialized all other elements in the first row and the then my codes get accepted. But still confused because all other elements in the first row are actually not used for calculation of the rest rows......

Comment: And why it always be 79..., can't figured out is this value by accident or a definitely = correct answer + 1...

Comment: I call the old codes 50 times and it seems my local machine resets the memory to zero each time and I get 50 correct answers... But my initialization does have bug and thanks for all of your helps~!